# Creating a webservice with proper layering in JavaEE

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, jax-rs

I am using Java EE for running my backend system and I have a question regarding how to layer it appropriately in terms of creating a web service.

I am pretty much organizing my application after the principles of DDD which means I have a domain layer, repository layer and a service layer. So the service layer are annotated with @Stateless and they are my EJBs.

Now, I could go crazy and annotate this service class with more annotations for the JAX-RS framework...but I don't know if this is correct for several reasons:

1. Wouldn't this mix the layering a bit?
2. How could I then version my webservice? Let say that I create a webservice today, and tomorrow I find out that it is really bad, however during the night someone have created an application that uses it and if I trash it the applications could no longer be used. What I want is a webservice that can be found on www.myurl.com/api/v1/customers
   and the new webservice on www.myurl.com/api/v2/a_new_customers_webservice

That is what I want in some sort.

There may be other cons too?

So what would the solution be? Am I correct if I say that I create another set of classes that I annotate with JAX-RS annotations and then the methods could internally use the methods from the EJBs in the service layer?

If there is going to be another webservice version I can create another set of classes that uses other URLs and logic. Or am I all wrong? How would you organize this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The underlying question is how to organize code for reuse. As you pointed out, you can:

1. annotate your EJB services with JAX-RS to make them web service;
2. create EJB web services (i.e. with JAX-RS annotations) that reuse other common EJB services (one level of indirection);
3. create EJB web services that reuse common logic as POJO (one level of indirection).

All three a valid choices to me.

If you're confident about the API of the EJB service, but not the API of the web service (there could be some impedance mismatch), I would go for 2.

If you are not confident about what your EJB service should do, then that's probably the first thing to figure out ;)

If you're confident *now*, but suspect it might change in the future, I would pick the simplest solution 1 for now, and refactor later as necessary depending on what must be changed. Apply [YAGNI](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/You_ain%27t_gonna_need_it).

Comment: Just so I understand what you mean: Number one will add the annotations on EJBs that is used for my service layer, and number two is the same as I mentioned; using another set of EJBs for webservices that uses the EJBs from the service layer?

Comment: @Dude yes, that's what I meant